# Panda lambda TypeError object float no len()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, lambda

Python Pandas lambda for update column with
`lambda x: np.nan if x == '0/0' else df['RatioFraction']`

Filter on one column then use lambda to change conditional on `np.nan` for no vote (0/0).

Received

```
TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()
```

Code:

```
df['RatioFraction'] = df_ff_reviews['VoteRatio'].apply(lambda x: np.nan if x == '0/0' else df['RatioFraction'])
```

Comment: How do I code the apply function, e.g., apply(str.len) inside this lambda function to remove the object type no len()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['RatioFraction'] = np.where(df['VoteRatio'] == '0/0', np.nan, df['VoteRation'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
df['RatioFraction'] = df_ff_reviews['VoteRatio']

df['RatioFraction'].loc[df['RatioFraction'] == '0/0'] = np.nan
```